# Cocos2d load animation from plist

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have found this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZyqGrdkTtM) for understanding how to create animation path for sprite using Adobe tools and plist file. But I still can't figure out how to create parser for this file. Is there already made solution how to do it or do I need to create it in my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will parse the file, load the texture, and create all the spriteFrame objects you need:

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"myFrames.plist"];
```